# Anyone good at cryptograms

Tags: cipher

I can't seem to solve this puzzle my friend gave me.

She did give me a hint:

The Song: Mary did You Know?

Picture attached below

[image]

Comment: It's Braille. On mobile right now so I can't decode it.

Comment: http://fontmeme.com/braille/#none for reference

Comment: I cropped the image slightly to remove the extra white space.

Answer (score 9):

Its braille for

> In every job that must be done
> There is an element of fun
> You find the fun and snap, the job's a game

Which is from

> 'A spoonful of sugar'

from the film

> Mary Poppins.

Which also fits the hint.

Comment: @user32481 Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left :-)